# xcode label.text will reset to default when change view

Tags: xcode, uilabel, uistoryboard, viewcontroller

I´am very new in Xcode and coding.Here is my problem. i have got two viewController an a NavigationController in my Storyboard. RootView is "StartView" and the Second View is "ViewController". in my ViewController are ten labels and every label is filled with a default text. For example in label1 is the Text "MyName". With an IBAction i will delete the text from a random label. Everything works fine. But when i go back to "RootView" and then back to the "ViewController" all Labels filled with the default Text. How could i fix this problem?

Comment: You do not have a data model. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller Then create a model to hold your data. When you initialize your view controller, initialize from your data model, not from the data you entered in the storyboard.

Comment: Ok. That means i have to work with Core data? Right?

Comment: That is one way to do it but that is probably way overkill. Read this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/45940/intro-object-oriented-design-part-1 and probably read all the tutorials on that page.